# facebook api permission check failing

Tags: facebook

```
if($facebook->api_client->users_hasAppPermission("status_update"))
echo 'yes'; 
else 
echo 'no';
```

Dont understand,its always printing the string 'NO' even if i allow status update permission

I tried with JS too

```
FB.Facebook.apiClient.users_hasAppPermission('status_update', function(result) 
{
      if(result)
        alert("yes");
      else
        alert("no");

});
```

Help me guys :(

Answer (score 1):

Because there is no status_update permission on Facebook. May be you need publish_stream permission? Check all permissions on official documentation http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your php, you should now be moving over to the Graph API as the REST api is soon to be deprecated.

Look for 'permissions' within 'connections' on this page for how to get an array of permissions back for a user: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/

As for your javascript, that is correct and results should be an integer 1 or 0.